# AWS glueContext read doesn't allow a sql query

Tags: aws-glue, mssql-jdbc

I want to read filtered data from a Mysql instance using AWS glue job. Since a glue jdbc connection doesnt allow me to push down predicate, I am trying to explicitly create a jdbc connection in my code.

I want to run a select query with where clause against a Mysql database using jdbc connection as shown below

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


object TryMe {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext()
    val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(sc)
    val spark: SparkSession = glueContext.getSparkSession

    // Read data into a DynamicFrame using the Data Catalog metadata
    val t = glueContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:mysql://serverIP:port/database").option("user","username").option("password","password").option("dbtable","select * from table1 where 1=1").option("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").load()

  }
}
```

It fails with error

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from
>   table1 where 1=1 WHERE 1=0' at line 1

Shouldn't this work? How do I retrieve filtered data using JDBC connection without reading the whole table into a data frame?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the problem occured because you didn't use the query in parentheses and provide an alias. In my opinion it should look like in the following example:

```
 val t = glueContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:mysql://serverIP:port/database").option("user","username").option("password","password").option("dbtable","(select * from table1 where 1=1) as t1").option("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").load()
```

More information about parameters in SQL data sources:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

When it comes to the Glue and the framework which the Glue provides, there is also the option "push_down_predicate", but I have only used this option on the data sources based on S3. I think it doesn't work on other sources than on S3 and non-partitioned data.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions.html

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is still searching for further answers/examples, I can confirm that the `push_down_predicate` option works with ODBC data sources. Here's how I read from SQL Server (in Python).

```
df = glueContext.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://server-ip:port;databaseName=db;")
    .option("user","username")
    .option("password","password")
    .option("dbtable","(select t1.*, t2.name from dbo.table1 t1 join dbo.table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id) as users")
    .option("driver","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
    .load()
```

This also works but NOT as I expected. The predicate is not pushed down to the data source.

```
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db", table_name = "db_dbo_table1", push_down_predicate = "(id >= 2850700 AND statusCode = 'ACT')")
```

The documentation on [`pushDownPredicate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) states: *The option to enable or disable predicate push-down into the JDBC data source. The default value is **true**, in which case Spark will push down filters to the JDBC data source as much as possible.*

Answer (score 1):

this are 5 different code snippets that i tried for performance comparison, only 2 actually filtered data on the server level when using profiler, it seems at the moment without creating a custom connector or buying from marketplace the only way to get this to work is using **glueContext.read**

You can [convert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html) DynamicFrames to and from DataFrames ([See example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-medicaid.html))

```
rds_datasink_temp = DynamicFrame.fromDF(rds_dataframe, glueContext, "nested")
```

you should also check this while running **Sql Server Profiler** with all the events from: **OLEDB**, **Stored Procedure**, **TSQL** and **Transactions**

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.context import DynamicFrame

# list parameter with 2 leading hyphens --param_server_url 
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,['JOB_NAME'])
print("JOB_NAME: ", args['JOB_NAME'])

job_server_url="SERVER URL"
job_db_name="DB NAME"
job_db_user="DB USER"
job_db_password="DB PASSWORD"
job_table_name="TABLE NAME"

job_glue_db_name="GLUE DATA CATALOG DATABASE NAME"
job_glue_conn_name="GLUE DATA CATALOG CONNECTION NAME"
job_glue_table_name="GLUE DATA CATALOG TABLE NAME"

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
region = "us-east-1"

#### aws glue data catalog table info (from ) ####
# Name  job_glue_table_name
# Database  job_glue_db_name
# Classification    sqlserver
# Location  job_db_name.dbo.job_table_name
# Connection    job_glue_conn_name

#### GlueContext Class ####
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html

#### DynamicFrame Class ####
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html

#### Connection Api ####
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_Connection.html

#### Using connectors and connections with AWS Glue Studio ####
# Link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/connectors-chapter.html
# Use AWS Secrets Manager for storing credentials
# Filtering the source data with row predicates and column projections 

#### Connection options for type custom.jdbc or marketplace.jdbc ####
# Link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-jdbc
# className – String, required, driver class name.
# connectionName – String, required, name of the connection that is associated with the connector.
# secretId or user/password – String, required, used to retrieve credentials for the URL.
# dbTable or query – String, required, the table or SQL query to get the data from. You can specify either dbTable or query, but not both.
# filterPredicate – String, optional, extra condition clause to filter data from source. For example:

# using \ for new line with more commands
# query="recordid<=5", -- filtering !
print("0001 - df_read_query")
df_read_query = glueContext.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://"+job_server_url+":1433;databaseName="+job_db_name+";") \
    .option("query","select recordid from "+job_table_name+" where recordid <= 5") \
    .option("user",job_db_user) \
    .option("password",job_db_password) \
    .load()
print("df_read_query count: ", df_read_query.count())
df_read_query.show(10)
df_read_query.printSchema()

# query="recordid<=5", -- not filtering
print("0002 - df_from_catalog_query")
df_from_catalog_query = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = job_glue_db_name, 
    table_name = job_glue_table_name, 
    additional_options={
        "query":"select recordid from "+job_table_name+" where recordid <= 5;",
    },
    transformation_ctx = "df_from_catalog_query", 
)
print("df_from_catalog_query count: ", df_from_catalog_query.count())
df_from_catalog_query.show(10)

# push_down_predicate="recordid<=5", -- not filtering
print("0003 - df_from_catalog_push_down_predicate")
df_from_catalog_push_down_predicate = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = job_glue_db_name, 
    table_name = job_db_name+'_dbo_'+job_table_name, 
    push_down_predicate = "recordid<=5",
    transformation_ctx = "df_from_catalog_push_down_predicate",
)
print("df_from_catalog_push_down_predicate count: ", df_from_catalog_push_down_predicate.count())
df_from_catalog_push_down_predicate.show(10)

# filterPredicate="recordid<=5", -- not filtering
print("0004 - df_from_options_sqlserver")
df_from_options_sqlserver = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type = "sqlserver", 
    connection_options = {
        "url":"jdbc:sqlserver://"+job_server_url+":1433;databaseName="+job_db_name+";",
        "username":job_db_user,
        "password":job_db_password,
        "location":job_db_name+".dbo."+job_table_name,
        "filterPredicate":"recordid<=5",
    }, 
    transformation_ctx = "df_from_options_sqlserver",
)
print("df_from_options_sqlserver count: ", df_from_options_sqlserver.count())
df_from_options_sqlserver.show(10)

# dbtable="recordid<=5", -- filtering !
print("0005 - df_read_dbtable")
df_read_dbtable = glueContext.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://"+job_server_url+":1433;databaseName="+job_db_name+";") \
    .option("user",job_db_user) \
    .option("password",job_db_password) \
    .option("dbtable","(select recordid from "+job_table_name+" where recordid<=5) as t1") \
    .option("driver","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .load()
print("df_read_dbtable count: ", df_read_dbtable.count())
df_read_dbtable.show(10)

job.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use create_dynamic_frame_from_options?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context-create_dynamic_frame_from_options